# swift, numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAt functions don't return values

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have an issue, numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAt functions don't return values. I need to return name and price from coincap.io/front API into tableView. I tried to change return values to integer and it works fine, but anyway I can't return another values.

Here is code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class Currency : NSObject {
    var name : String!
    var price : Double!

    init(name : String, price : Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    let DATA_URL : String = "http://coincap.io/front"
    var currencies = [Currency]()
    var counter = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        getData(url: DATA_URL)
    }

    func getData(url: String) {
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                print("Success! Got the data")
                let dataJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
              // print(dataJSON)
                self.updateData(json: dataJSON)
            } else {
                print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
            }
        }
    }

    func updateData(json: JSON) {
        for (_, current) in json{
            currencies.append(Currency(name: current["long"].stringValue, price: current["price"].doubleValue))
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return NSInteger(counter)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "currencyCell", for: indexPath)
        let current = currencies[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = current.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(current.price!)"
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's you attempt to reload the table view once the data is loaded from Alamofire?

Comment: Here is my full code. Sorry, I'm newbie, what reload you're telling about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call reload

```
func getData(url: String) {
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON { response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            print("Success! Got the data")
            let dataJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
          // print(dataJSON)
            self.updateData(json: dataJSON)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {self.tableView.reloadData()}
        } else {
            print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
        }
    }
}
```

Also replace

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return NSInteger(counter)
}
```

with

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return  currencies.count
}
```

Comment: Thank you! now code looks:   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {self.tableView.reloadData()}
        return currencies.count
       
    }